# Drag and Drop working fine on IE but not in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I'm working on a project in asp.net C# with Visual Studio 2013.
I generated some div in the code behind and I affect them a css class, in the Page_PreRender().

Code Behind C#:

```
HtmlGenericControl divRessource = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
divRessource.Attributes.Add("id", "div" + i.ToString());
divRessource.Attributes.Add("class", "dragRessources");
```

These div need to be draggable and droppable in a table generated in code behind too.
So, I use Jquery 1.6.4 and Jquery-ui 1.10.3 to make this.

Here is my JS code :

```
$(function () {
 $_dropEnd = null;

 $(".dragRessources").draggable({
   helper: "clone",
   revert: 'invalid',
   appendTo: "body",

   stop: function (event, ui) {
     $(this).appendTo($_dropEnd);

     $_dropEnd = null;
   }
  });

  $(".dropRessources").droppable({
    accept: ".dragRessources",
    tolerance: "touch",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
    $_dropEnd = this;  
   }
  });
});
```

CSS :

```
.dragRessources{
    cursor: move;
    color:Black;
    pointer-events: none;
    background-color:transparent;
    width:auto;
}
```

HTML (The div takes place in the `divTabRessources`):

```
<div id="divRessources" class="divRessources" runat="server" style="display:none;" >
   <div id="divTabRessources" class="divTabRessources dropRessources" style="display:block;" runat="server"></div>
</div>
```

My problem here is that the drag and drop works fine on IE 10 and below but I can't drag the div on Chrome and Firefox. Actually the mouse cursor isn't even changing in firefox and chrome.

Anyone know where is the problem? I'm sorry if it's an easy question but I'm in this project for a while now and I may miss something obvious...

Comment: It's working http://jsfiddle.net/BJBa9/1/.  Can you be specific? and share your HTML, CSS and JS code.

Comment: @MuthuKumaran I can't really be more specific. The code work fine in IE but not in the other navigator, and I don't know why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me (IE, FF, Chrome) if I remove the

```
pointer-events: none;
```

css statement. 
With this statement enabled it does not even run in IE.
See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5u5DQ/)

Due to [CSS tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/) *pointer-events*: *none*

> prevents all click, state and cursor options on the specified HTML element

Comment: I was using this attribute for a mouseover event who didn't trigger when I'm dragging a div because the focus is set on the drag element and not on the element behind the div.